# Python Bokeh: How can i use Python callbacks or external functions while having HTML/JS output

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, bokeh

I'm currently creating a dynamic map, which presents the absolute fertility from ~1960 -> 2015. Creating a static map is no problem whatsoever, but i can't create a dynamic slider in order to switch between different timestamps (years in this context). I currently get the following error, while using my function:

```
You are generating standalone HTML/JS output, but trying to use real Python
callbacks (i.e. with on_change or on_event). This combination cannot work.

Only JavaScript callbacks may be used with standalone output. For more
information on JavaScript callbacks with Bokeh, see:

    http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html

Alternatively, to use real Python callbacks, a Bokeh server application may
be used. For more information on building and running Bokeh applications, see:

    http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html
```

I followed the links that are mentioned in the error code, but i don't get it honestly.
My code is mentioned below, i don't get, where i do need to use an external function, because i can't use the python callback. Thanks so much in advance.

My code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Dec  2 11:20:18 2019

@author: User
"""

import geopandas as gpd # Package zum Einlesen von Shapefiles

shapefile ='C:/Users/User/Desktop/Programmierung_aktuell/Interaktive Map/ne_110m_admin_0_countries/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp'

# Shapefile wird mittels Geopandas gelesen und in gdf gespeichert
gdf = gpd.read_file(shapefile)[['ADMIN', 'ADM0_A3', 'geometry']]

# Oberste Zeile wird neu benannt
gdf.columns = ['country', 'country_code', 'geometry'] # Die oberste Zeile wird umbenannnt (nice to have)

gdf.head()

print(gdf[gdf['country'] == 'Antarctica']) # Als Test wird einmal Antarktik ausgegeben

# Die Spalte, die mit Antarktik korrespondiert, wird gelöscht

gdf = gdf.drop(gdf.index[159])

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import pandas as pd

datafile = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Programmierung_aktuell/Interaktive Map/children-per-woman-UN.csv' # Excel-Tabelle wird mit Panda eingelesen

df = pd.read_csv(datafile, names = ['entity', 'code', 'year', 'fertility-absolut'], skiprows = 1) # Eine Spalte wird übersprungen

df.head()
df.info()
df[df['code'].isnull()]

# Daten werden für das Jahr 2015 gefiltert
df_2015 = df[df['year'] == 2015]
# Dataframes von 2015 und die Polgygone der Karte werden auf Basis des Namens und Codes gemerged.
merged = gdf.merge(df_2015, left_on = 'country_code', right_on = 'code')

#----------------------------------------------------
# Was haben wir jetzt?
# Einen Dataframe,der die Fertilitätsraten aller Länder im Jahr 2015 enthält

import json
# Dataframe wird in json konvertiert; Loads ist der Standard-json-encoder
merged_json = json.loads(merged.to_json())

# Der json-Dataframe wird in einen String konvertiert; Dumps ist der Standard string-converter
json_data = json.dumps(merged_json)

from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import GeoJSONDataSource, LinearColorMapper, ColorBar
from bokeh.palettes import brewer

# GeoJSON-Quelle, die die Features für das Plotten enthält, kriegt den Input
geosource = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = json_data)

# Mehrfarbige Palette wird definiert
palette = brewer['YlGnBu'][8]

# Palette wird mit *(-1) umgekehrt, wodurch die dunkelste Farbe, die höchste Fertilität ausdrückt
palette = palette[::-1]

# Instantiate LinearColorMapper that linearly maps numbers in a range, into a sequence of colors.

color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette = palette, low = 0, high = 4)

#Define custom tick labels for color bar.
tick_labels = {'4': '>4'}

#Create color bar. 
color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper, label_standoff=8,width = 500, height = 20,
border_line_color=None,location = (0,0), orientation = 'horizontal', major_label_overrides = tick_labels)

#Create figure object.
p = figure(title = 'Absolute Fertility, 2015', plot_height = 600 , plot_width = 950, toolbar_location = None)
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None

#Add patch renderer to figure. 
p.patches('xs','ys', source = geosource,fill_color = {'field' :'fertility-absolut', 'transform' : color_mapper},
          line_color = 'black', line_width = 0.25, fill_alpha = 1)
#Specify figure layout.
p.add_layout(color_bar, 'below')
#Display figure inline in Jupyter Notebook.
output_notebook()
#Display figure.
show(p)

df_2015 = df[df['year'] == 2015]


#Instantiate LinearColorMapper that maps numbers in a range linearly into a sequence of colors. Input nan_color.
color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette = palette, low = 0, high = 40, nan_color = '#d9d9d9')

from bokeh.io import curdoc, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import Slider, HoverTool
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, row, column
from bokeh.models.callbacks import CustomJS


#Define function that returns json_data for year selected by user.

def json_data(selectedYear):
    yr = selectedYear
    df_yr = df[df['year'] == yr]
    merged = gdf.merge(df_yr, left_on = 'country_code', right_on =     'code', how = 'left')
    #merged.fillna('No data', inplace = True)
    merged = merged.replace('No data', inplace = True)
    merged_json = json.loads(merged.to_json())
    json_data = json.dumps(merged_json)
    return json_data

#Input GeoJSON source that contains features for plotting.
geosource = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = json_data(2015))

#Define a sequential multi-hue color palette.
palette = brewer['YlGnBu'][8]

#Reverse color order so that dark blue is highest obesity.
palette = palette[::-1]

#Instantiate LinearColorMapper that linearly maps numbers in a range, into a sequence of colors. Input nan_color.
color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette = palette, low = 0, high = 40, nan_color = '#d9d9d9')

#Define custom tick labels for color bar.
tick_labels = {'0,5': '0,5', '1':'1','1,5':'1,5','2':'2', '2,5':'2,5', '3':'3', '3,5':'3,5', '4': '4'}

#Add hover tool
hover = HoverTool(tooltips = [ ('Country/region','@country'),('fertility-absolut', 'fertility-absolut')])
#Create color bar. 
color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper, label_standoff=8,width = 500, height = 20,
                     border_line_color=None,location = (0,0), orientation = 'horizontal', major_label_overrides = tick_labels)
#Create figure object.
p = figure(title = 'Absolute fertility', plot_height = 600 , plot_width = 950, toolbar_location = None, tools = [hover])
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
#Add patch renderer to figure. 
p.patches('xs','ys', source = geosource,fill_color = {'field' :'fertility-absolut', 'transform' : color_mapper},
          line_color = 'black', line_width = 0.25, fill_alpha = 1)
#Specify layout
p.add_layout(color_bar, 'below')
# Define the callback function: update_plot

def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    yr = slider.value
    new_data = json_data(yr)
    geosource.geojson = new_data
    p.title.text = 'Absolute fertility' %yr

# Make a slider object: slider 
slider = Slider(title = 'Year',start = 1975, end = 2015, step = 1, value = 2015)
slider.on_change('value', update_plot)
# Make a column layout of widgetbox(slider) and plot, and add it to the current document
layout = column(p,widgetbox(slider))
curdoc().add_root(layout)
#Display plot inline in Jupyter notebook
output_notebook()
#Display plot
show(layout)
```

Comment: The output of `show(layout)` is just plain HTML/JS with no connection to any Python process, so there is no possibility to have real Python callbacks with `on_change` (because a HTML in a browser cannot run Python code). To have real Python callbacks you have to use a Bokeh server app, either one you run yourself or that you embed in a notebook (see the link in the other answer).

Comment: Good point, thanks a lot. So far, i don't get how to show anything on the Bokeh Server app. 
As a command in prompt, i used "bokeh serve --show Program.ipynb"
And through curdoc.add_root(layout), i should see something, but the application is empty. Can you help me?

Comment: For open ended questions like this please come over to the Project Discourse (with a complete, minimal example to share) https://discourse.bokeh.org/